# I am making some style buttons using javascript but they are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm making some style buttons using javascript but they are not working.

I have been struggled with this several hours.

Here is my code:

`Html:`

```
<textarea><textarea>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','10px',0)">Small</button>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','20px',1)">Medium</button>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','30px',2)">Large</button>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','40px',3)">Extra Large</button>
```

`JavaScript:`

```
function size(stys,sizes,i){
                let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')
                document.querySelector('textarea').style.stys = sizes;
                console.log(document.querySelector('textarea').style.stys)
                for(let y = 0;y<buttons.length;y++){
                   buttons[y].style.textDecoration = 'none'
                }   
                 buttons[i].style.textDecoration = 'underline'
            }
```

I'm not sure why, but the font size doesn't style to the textarea even though the `console.log` return the font size i want to style to.

Thanks for anyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.style.stys` to `.style[stys]`:

```js
function size(stys,sizes,i){
    let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')
    document.querySelector('textarea').style[stys] = sizes;
    console.log(document.querySelector('textarea').style[stys])
    for(let y = 0;y<buttons.length;y++){
       buttons[y].style.textDecoration = 'none'
    }   
     buttons[i].style.textDecoration = 'underline'
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','10px',0)">Small</button>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','20px',1)">Medium</button>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','30px',2)">Large</button>
<button onclick = "size('fontSize','40px',3)">Extra Large</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding me so quickly. it works pretty well. Could you explain to me t the reason that i should use `.style[stys]`? I can't figure it out! Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you want to target dynamic property you put it in brackets

Comment: Thanks for classifications. :). I will accept your answer:)